Writing UTF-16 directly to stdout with fwrite not doing what's expected
I'm trying to figure out how to write to the console in UTF-16 mode directly (without wprintf) as part of a solution to another problem and wanted to do this directly in C first. Here is an example of the problem:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); // Comment out for non-Unicode output

    wchar_t temp[] = { L'A', 0x2588, L'C', L'D', L'\n', 0 };
    // char temp[] = { 'A', 'C', 'D', '\n', 0 };

    wprintf(temp); // prints "A█CD\n" as expected
    // printf(temp);

    fwrite(temp, sizeof *temp, 4, stdout); // Doesn't print anything
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}

If you comment out the _setmode(...) and uncomment the other parts for regular printf, you'll see that fwrite acts just like printf and prints "ACD\n". When you do this current example fwrite just doesn't display anything. Why?
I piped the program to a text file, and the data is there, but it just won't display to stdout.
I've looked for similar questions and Google had nothing for me. Bing Copilot (ChatGPT) had nothing for me either.

Does it work when you comment out the wprintf()?

https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.c/c/FVGqznW8Cao – looks like wprintf(L"%ls", temp) or fputws(temp, stdout) might be the best way, unfortunately.

@Shawn Commenting it out just results in nothing displayed in the console.

You can convert utf16 to utf8 with a single function and print it with printf. see this

Try putting stdout in binary mode rather than _O_U16TEXT.

in modern Windows you should use UTF-8 to avoid issues like this and maintain cross-platform code easier

Thanks to Ry-, the answer is to use fputws(temp, stdout) unfortunately.
